# Spring Boot Error 404 Not Found GetMapping

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-restcontroller

I am new to spring boot and am trying to use the RestController to create API Endpoints. When I try to call the endpoint, it gives me error 404 not found which results to While label  error page being displayed in the browser

Application Class:

```
package com.guider.guiderfinder;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.guider")
public class GuiderFinderApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GuiderFinderApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Controller Class:

```
package com.guider.guiderfinder.controller;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.guider.guiderfinder.model.Guide;
import com.guider.guiderfinder.repository.GuideRepository;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/") //Standard url endpoint defined
public class GuideController {
    
    @Autowired
    private GuideRepository guideRepository;
    
    @GetMapping("/guides") //this api endpoint is called from url = localhost:8080/api/v1/guides
    public List<Guide> getAllGuides() {
        System.out.println("API was hit");
        return guideRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

pox.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.guider</groupId>
    <artifactId>guider-finder</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>guider-finder</name>
    <description>Backend of guide finder</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>          
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-devtools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.javydreamercsw/MySQL-Driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.javydreamercsw</groupId>
            <artifactId>MySQL-Driver</artifactId>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write `@ComponentScan("com.guider")` you are telling Spring to only scan in this directory. Your controller is in a sub-directory. Using `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.guider")` should solve your problem. An alternative is to add additional packages to scan. An example of this that would pick up your controller is `@ComponentScan({"com.guider", "com.guider.guiderfinder"})`.

Comment: I tried that. It doesn't work. Is my controller file correct?

Comment: What's the URL you are hitting? I created a sample project with your code, minus the repository and I can reach the endpoint.

Comment: http://localhost:8081/api/v1/guides

NOTE: I have configured application.properties to start the server at port 8081.

Comment: I think the problem might be in my pom.xml. I created a new project and it worked there. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what's going on with your app. You don't really need the ``@EnableAutoConfiguration`` or the 
``@ComponentScan("com.guider")``. Remove them and see what happens. Did you use Spring Initializr to create your project?

Comment: In the new project I don't have ```@EnableAutoConfiguration``` and ```@ComponentScan``` and it works fine. I don't know what was wrong with the old project but like I said it has to do something with pom.xml. pom.xml showed that it had some error when we see the file icon from project explorer but when I open the file there was no error being shown